# Dapr kafka partition key with python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, fastapi, dapr

I have a Dapr pub/sub component using kafka as broker and I need to get the partion key of the messages.

I publish the messages in a kafka topic from an external application, without using Dapr and neither using the cloudevents format.

Then, I use the dapr Fastapi python SDK to subscribe to the topic and I can get all the raw messages published in the topic.

But I need to retrieve also the partition key of the message, is it possible?

Thanks